# If $x \rightarrow \lambda x$ is called scaling of $x$, what is the transformation $x^\lambda$ called?

Tags: terminology

What do you call, in general, the transformation $x^\lambda$ when $\lambda$ is any arbitrary number? When $\lambda$ is 2, 3, 4, 5 respectively, do you think it is meaningful to call this a quadratic, cubic, quartic, quintic (respectively) transformation of $x$?

Comment: ... exponentiation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation

Answer (score 2):

From a comment by @janmarqz : the operation is called exponentiation. (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation)

Yet, exponentiation does not only refer to $x^\lambda$, it also refers to $\lambda^x$.